# mysql запрос для поиска по одному из нескольких слов в строке

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

В моей БД есть колонка **name** и в ней данные такого формата:

```
['grot', 'tyrex', 'kolder']
```

Я хочу вывести все данные, ориентируясь на **tyrex**.
Но когда я создаю запрос в `php`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` = 'tyrex'");
```

То ничего не происходит. Так как, видимо, поиск идет по всей строке и она должна совпадать полностью.

> **Как сделать поиск (фильтр) по одному из значений?**

Возможно, вопрос совсем для новичков. Но поиски ответа в интернете меня ни к чему не привели :(

Comment: `name` like '%tyrex%'

Comment: сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поиска подстроки в поле используется оператор **like**

```
column like '%searchValue%'
```

Если надо найти "Строка начинается с"

```
column like '%searchValue'
```

Строка заканчивается на

```
column like 'searchValue%'
```